# Flutter image_picker plugin and overlay

Tags: flutter, overlay

I am looking to achieve something like following while capturing image camera preview is on but could not get idea how I can achieve with [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package.

[Camera Preview Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsvGJ.jpg)

Finally, image I wanted to capture would be only the content in highlighted circle. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

r/Pat.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve what you want with an image picker package.

What can help you is
Camera pulgin->https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Camera plugin gives you a live camera preview in your widget.
Create a stateful or stateless widget and use a camera plugin to customize that widget and capture only what you want.

You can also ref to this question ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711650/flutter-camera-preview-in-small-widget-not-in-full-screen/64711764?noredirect=1#comment114421575_64711764

Happy coding!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the details Jigar. I can definitely see more customization options in Camera plugin but still nowhere near to my result. I will try more with Camera plugin and post solution here if I get success. Thanks once again for the help.